# Polymer core-header-panel and core-drawer-toggle menu items disappear

Tags: polymer

In my app I am using core-drawer-toggle to toogle after clicking the menu-item.
Sample:

```
<core-scaffold id="core_scaffold">
  <core-header-panel mode="seamed" id="core_header_panel" navigation flex>
    <core-toolbar id="core_toolbar"></core-toolbar>
    <core-menu selected="Item1" valueattr="label" selectedindex="0" id="core_menu" theme="core-light-theme">
      <core-item id="core_item" core-drawer-toggle horizontal center layout icon="settings" label="Item1" active></core-item>
      <core-item id="core_item1" core-drawer-toggle horizontal center layout icon="settings" label="Item2"></core-item>
    </core-menu>
  </core-header-panel>
  <div id="div" tool>Title</div>
</core-scaffold>
```

This works fine with chrome in wide and narrow layout.

With firefox and safari it also works fine in the narrow layout. But when I resize the window to wide with safari and firefox the menue-items disappear.
Can I use core-drawer-toggle and display the menu items in the wide layout?

Comment: What versions of safari and firefox? I assume it's using the latest versions and not an issue with (not/)using the webcomponents polyfill?

Comment: Polymer  "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^0.5.4" and Firefox V35.0.1 Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way. core-scaffold has a method "togglePanel" (see example)

```
<core-scaffold id="core_scaffold">
  <core-header-panel mode="seamed" id="core_header_panel" navigation flex>
    <core-toolbar id="core_toolbar"></core-toolbar>
    <core-menu selected="Item1" valueattr="label" selectedindex="0" id="core_menu" theme="core-light-theme">
      <core-item label="Item1" icon="settings" size="24" id="core_item" on-tap="{{ doSomething }}" horizontal center layout active></core-item>
      <core-item label="Item2" icon="settings" size="24" id="core_item1" horizontal center layout></core-item>
    </core-menu>
  </core-header-panel>
  <div id="div" tool>Title</div>
</core-scaffold>
```

```
Polymer('my-element', {
  doSomething: function (){
    this.$.core_scaffold.togglePanel();
  }
});
```